# How to get current month records from RDBMS without using DATE functions like CURDATE,MONTH,YEAR

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, date, substring

I want to write sql compatibility query for mysql nad sqlite3.
in mysql i wrote a query to get current month records as

so_date is date field(YYYY-MM-DD)

```
select so_no,so_date from so_master where MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(so_date) AND YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(so_date);
```

this is not working in sqlite3.
in sqlite I can write like

```
 select so_no,so_date from so_master where strftime('%Y-%m', so_date) = strftime('%Y-%m', 'now');
```

but my application cannot work if i change the database like mysql to sqlite3 or sqlite3 to mysql

so i want my query to work in both the databases with one query.

Comment: Sadly databases usually have their own specific date APIs, and they are not at all mutually exchangeable.  As a result, you are basically stuck with vendor specific code if you are doing complex date operations.

Comment: 'so i want my query to work in both the databases with one query' - short answer you can't, sql dialects differ, sometimes significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you treat the dates as strings with the the function `SUBSTR()` and `CURRENT_DATE` which is common in both MySql and SQLite:

```
SELECT so_no, so_date 
FROM so_master 
WHERE SUBSTR(so_date, 6, 2) = SUBSTR(CURRENT_DATE, 6, 2)
  AND SUBSTR(so_date, 1, 4) = SUBSTR(CURRENT_DATE, 1, 4);
```

Or, simpler:

```
SELECT so_no, so_date 
FROM so_master 
WHERE SUBSTR(so_date, 1, 7) = SUBSTR(CURRENT_DATE, 1, 7);
```

Demo [for SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5b2a09b63ff23fce2bb406824a457cca) and [for MySql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b2a09b63ff23fce2bb406824a457cca).